# Cannot Disable Sticky Edges on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: display, 16.10, display-manager

I cannot disable Sticky Edges on Ubuntu 16.10. This happened to my only after I upgraded my Ubuntu from 16.04 to 16.10.

Even though I check the sticky edges option to be OFF on Displays Settings, that is still acting the same.

[My options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjs6y.png) (screenshot) on Display Manager

Comment: Have you tried using Unity Tweak Tool?

Comment: Well, its kind of an old question which unfortunately I don't quite remember now what I've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a reference for someone who might have the same issue, I was not able to fix this issue until I updated to Ubuntu 17.04!